# What is wrong with this filing cabinet lock mechanism, and what options do I have to improve it?

Tags: lock

I recently got hold of a second hand filing cabinet. I do not have keys for it.

When I put some hanging files in the top drawer, I noticed that upon closing the drawer, the part of the file that hangs over the drawer edge would be pushed under a metal plate, which it would catch one when opening the drawer again (images attached to demonstrate). This plate appears to be part of the lock mechanism, but currently does not seem to be attached to it. I removed the top drawer to examine it more closely, and the part of the lock that is attached to the front of the cabinet has a Phillips head screw, presumably for removal.

[image: inside of cabinet showing broken lock]
[image: detail of how broken lock interferes with drawer]

I found this video, which mentions using the key, and then a core removal key, but this doesn't address my issue of the out of place plate (and I have neither of these keys). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC2plKOLLio

Is there any possibility of installing a new lock (which would come with a key) by unscrewing the current lock from behind? Would it be possible to fix the mechanism in the process? If not, is there something I can do to at least get that plate out of the way so that files do not catch on it?

Comment: In normal operation the bracket is up in the unlocked position. Then it will not hit anything as the drawer moves in and out. The bracket lowers in the locked position. Nothing will hit because the drawer does not move while the cabinet is locked.

Answer (score 2):

Usually those locks have a nut behind - that is how they are held in place. If not then there is a type of spring clip - you need to look.

Then you need to get the plate fixed back into the correct position if you want the locking system to work. Or remove it and not worry about that locking system.

If you **need** to secure that cabinet shut then a rod straight down the front through a couple of added brackets will work with a padlock.

Just be aware that a cabinet like that can be opened like a can if they really want the stuff.

Comment: Do you mean that the screw I mentioned should also have a nut or spring clip? I don't remember seeing either of those, but I'll have another look when I get a chance.

Any advice one how exactly to fix the plate back into the correct position? I did try pulling it back up by hand, but it didn't want to budge.

Comment: The plate will need to be bent with pliers or vise grips or carefully with a hammer. The nut or spring clip is on the back side of the lock holding it tight. I'm thinking now that that screw goes into the side of the lock just enough to keep it in place. Never seen that though.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket had been bent backwards (screwdriver and hammer) to force it of the end of the lockbar on back of lock.

That lockbar normally fits inside the "L" cutout on the bracket which just hangs there. Rotation of the key would turn the bar to move the bracket up or down. A little elbow grease and pliers and it could be bent farther back to be parallel to the drawer if locking the cabinet is not a concern.

**Or:** remove the lock via the nut or spring clip as mentioned in the above answer. Take the same pliers and elbow grease and bend it back parallel to the front and lift it with one hand and insert new key assembly to hang bracket as describe above.

[Replacement locks](https://www.amazon.com/file-cabinet-lock-kit/s?k=file%20cabinet%20lock%20kit) are easily obtained. Compare your old one to find exact match.

Comment: No, the top drawer doesn't stick out. I don't doubt what you're saying, but so that I can understand better, if the bracket has "fallen into the locked position", then why is the cabinet still unlocked?

Comment: My mistake. It should have said has fallen **from** the locked position. I will edit the answer, adding more info as well.

Comment: I had a similar scenario where the bracket had been bent and prevented the drawer from closing another 1/4 inch. Did you try lifting on the bracket to see how loose it is? It could be as simple as wedging something next to the bracket to hold it up higher without engaging the lock.

Comment: I did try lifting it, it doesn't seem to want to budge at all. Possibly explains why it was just bent back. I will try to play with it again next time I have a chance.

Okay, if it has fallen from the locked position, why would the unlocked position be an obstruction for the hanging file? Or has this somehow fallen further than it should have, because there's no nut to keep it attached to the bar on the lock?

Comment: The unlocked position of the lockbar is still higher then where the bracket currently is. Because there was no key to unlock and rotate the core and lockbar the bracket was forced backwards off the lockbar allowing it to drop too far. I would remove the next drawer down and look to see how this bracket might of locked that drawer, such as some sort of catch, also, how many drawers are there? If It's 3 or under, you might want to flip the cabinet upside down or on it's side (remove all drawers) and look underneath.

Comment: There are three drawers. What are you expecting to find under the cabinet? I didn't see anything unexpected there when I was moving it.

Comment: That bar that is bentr would need to go all the way down to bottom drawer in order to lock all drawers. I was just curious if there was anything that might shine more light on the issue. I will be taking items to a thrift store this week. If they have a cabinet I will look at it to see if it is similar to try diagnosing yours.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's all internal to the cabinet chassis. All I can remember seeing on the bottom is the metallic base, which sits on the floor.